# Getting two dividing random numbers using java

Tags: java

Is there any way to get 2 random numbers that can be divided ?.For example number1 and number2
are two random number between 1 to 10 and i want to generate number1 which is divided by number2.
Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase.

Comment: What have you tried? What results did you get? What results were you expecting?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply generate a random number and then generate another number and multiply it with the first one to obtain the second number.

Answer (score 3):

By Brute-Force you can simply loop on all the interval you want like from 1-10.

```
int N=10;
for (int i=1; i<= N; i++){
    for (int j=1; j<= N; j++){
         if (i%j==0){
             System.out.println(i+" " + j);
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to simply generate two integer numbers between 1 and 10 (inclusive).
The method `nextInt(int)` of the `Random` class can be used to generate a random integer number. Since it generates a number between 0 (inclusive) and the given argument (exclusive), the result must be multiplied by 10, resulting in an integer from 0 to 10 (exclusive). Now just add 1 to obtain a number between 1 and 10 (inclusive).

Example:

```
import java.util.Random;

private final Random random = new Random();

private int random10() {
    return 1 + random.nextInt(10);
}
```

(to get 2 numbers, just call it twice)